# How to find second derivative of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, derivatives

How do I find the second derivative of the next function:

$$ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt  $$

I've tried to solve it using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the chain rule, but i'm not sure if my approach is correct.

$$ f'(x) = F'(x^2/2) - F'(-\infty) \ where \ F \ is \ the \ antiderivative \\ f'(x) = e^{x - x^4/8} - e^{x - (-\infty)^2/2} \\ f'(x) = e^{x - x^4/8} - e^{-\infty} = e^{x - x^4/8} \\ f''(x) = e^{x-x^4/8}(1-x^3/2)$$

Comment: You use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, as you suggested. If you post your attempt, we can tell you if you're going about it the right way.

Comment: I assume you mean with respect to $x$?

Comment: @Shai Obviously, since the function $f$ is defined only in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to write
$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt
= e^x \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{x^2/2} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \; dt}_{g(x)}
=e^x g(x).
$$
Then, from the product rule, we get$$f'(x) = e^x g(x) + e^x g'(x)$$ and \begin{align*}
f''(x) &= (e^x g(x) + e^x g'(x)) + (e^x g'(x) + e^x g''(x)) \\
&= e^x g(x) + 2e^x g'(x) + e^x g''(x).
\end{align*}

The only thing that's  left is $g'(x)$ and $g''(x)$, which are calculated with FTC and chain rule. Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's the product rule, not the chain rule, and you haven't really answered the question without formulae for $g'(x)$ and $g''(x)$.  (For the record, by FTC and the actual chain rule, (I was wrong.  I don't want to try again lest I miss the edit deadline.  I'll be back.).)

Comment: Woops meant product rule  . . .

Comment: I've updated the question with my way

Comment: Sorry.  $g'(x) = xe^{-x^4/8}$, $g''(x) = e^{-x^4/8} - \frac{x^2e^{-x^4/8}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Also, could you spot the mistake in my approach? (our results are close)

Comment: So you assume that the derivative of inifinity is 0?

Comment: Bogdan Pop, it looks like you make two mistakes in your solution.  First, you don't actually use the chain rule, because for the chain rule you would need to multiply by the derivative of the parameter.  Second, you're treating $e^x$ as a constant (as is user288742 in their most recent solution), and you can't do that.